# Maintain five section in DOM at a time

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating Ebook Reader, Now I want to fetch sections of ebook from link :

```
 http://tmaserv.scem.uws.edu.au/chapters/?n=0   It will fetch Section number 0
 http://tmaserv.scem.uws.edu.au/chapters/?n=1   It will fetch Section number 1
 ..
 so on
```

Number of sections can be obtained from url http://tmaserv.scem.uws.edu.au/chapters

Now, I am able to fetch a section, but what I want is reader should maintain 5 sections of the document in the DOM at any time.Also we can only fetch one section at a time. First 5 will be fetched will document loads,then additional sections are fetched on request.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>EBook</title>
<script>
var requestNum = 0;
// assume I had fetched the number of sections in varibale say sectionCount
function do_exercise () {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // adjust the GET URL to reflect the new n value and request as before
    x.open('GET', 'http://tmaserv.scem.uws.edu.au/chapters/?n=' + requestNum, true);
    x.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status ==200) {
            obj = (x.responseText);
            JSON.parse(x.responseText);
            obj = JSON.parse(obj);
            document.getElementById("section1").innerHTML = obj.data;
            requestNum++;
        }
    }

    x.send(null);
}
</script>
<body>
<nav>           
    <button onclick="do_exercise();">Next section</button>      
</nav>
<section id = "section1">
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Should I use some array to get 5 sections and maintain them?

Comment: You said DOM but your code is all Javascript, so do you mean in the client's memory via javascript or are you going to load it all into the DOM.

Comment: @Leeish I need to load it in DOM

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/28gtdyot/

```js
var cacheSize = 5;
var chapters = [];
var requestNum = 0;

function fetchChapter() {
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // adjust the GET URL to reflect the new n value and request as before
  x.open('GET', 'http://tmaserv.scem.uws.edu.au/chapters/?n=' + requestNum++, true);
  x.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
      obj = (x.responseText);
      JSON.parse(x.responseText);
      obj = JSON.parse(obj);
      chapters.push(obj.data);
      if (chapters.length > cacheSize) {
        chapters.shift();
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < chapters.length; ++i) {
        document.getElementById("section" + i).innerHTML = chapters[i];
      }
    }
  }

  x.send(null);
}
```